# Hibernate/JPA: Dynamically create a count Query based on another Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, hibernate-criteria

Is there a JPA-specific or provider-specific way to create a `javax.persistence.Query/TypedQuery` from another `Query/TypedQuery` with the possibility to change the query parts like the `Selection`? Basically, I would like to get the number of entities that a `javax.persistence.Query` could possibly return before actually running it.

Comment: This is straightforward, if you are willing to use the criteria API. But then, the criteria API is cumbersome, so this should be a informed decision. I don't think this is possible with JPQL "string" queries or native queries.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I'm actually trying to find a method to implement this without having to go through all the existing criteria and JPQL-based queries just to add the count query. Basically, I'm trying to implement a `getPotentialResultCount(Query)` method to cater to all existing and new queries.